# prestashop products as variation of other products

Tags: prestashop-1.5

i have a question.
I use Prestashop v1.5.6.0

I have a database with all product, but with a unique code for product.
I'd like combinate them.
For example. i have 2 pen:
Pen 1 with code 001 color black
Pen 2 with code 002 color red
they appartain at the same model, two pen are identical, the only difference is the color, but in database they are two distinct items.

Can i combine them ? WebService ? Script PHP ?
Is it possibile ?

Thanks and excuse me for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is product combinations : http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Adding+Products+and+Product+Categories#AddingProductsandProductCategories-AddingProductCombinations

Comment: Not Exaclty. I'd like that a product in database become an attribute of another product. For example two product in database, with two id and two reference code that are same, identical but with different color, o different size. Is it possibile combine them ? How ?